# AWS Codepipeline Spring boot War file

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, aws-codepipeline

I have a Spring Boot Application with gradle as the dependency manager. I have been creating the war file using Export As war file. And have deployed the same in AWS ElasticBeanstalk. The platform I use is `Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.4.5`

Now, I want to use CI/CD of AWS and want to create a Code Pipeline to deploy the war file to EBS.

While creating the Code-Pipeline, it asks me to build the Code Build Project.

Following is my build command :

```
version: 0.2

#env:
  #variables:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #parameter-store:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #secrets-manager:
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
  #exported-variables:
     # - variable
     # - variable
  #git-credential-helper: yes
#batch:
  #fast-fail: true
  #build-list:
  #build-matrix:
  #build-graph:
phases:
  #install:
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    #runtime-versions:
      # name: version
      # name: version
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  #pre_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
      - gradle build
      # - command
  #post_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
#reports:
  #report-name-or-arn:
    #files:
      # - location
      # - location
    #base-directory: location
    #discard-paths: yes
    #file-format: JunitXml | CucumberJson
#artifacts:
  #files:
    # - location
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

What changes do I make here, so that the war file is created and deployed to EBS. Since, I am pretty new to the Build Process and CI/CD, I am a bit confused.

My build.gradle file is :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    
    //compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.4.15.Final'
    
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
    
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.0'
    
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    
    
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.784'
    
    providedCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '0.11.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.18'
    
    
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
    
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
    
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.mojo', name: 'exec-maven-plugin', version: '3.0.0'
    
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    
    compile group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'core', version: '3.4.1'
    
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    
    
    implementation group: 'com.google.common', name: 'google-collect', version: '0.5'
    
    
    
    
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    
    
    
    
    
    //testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem a few days ago and I hardly found any good resources for gradle. You can easily deploy your application directly to Elastic Beanstalk by uploading a WAR file generated during the gradle build.

When you upload your WAR file to Beanstalk, it gets extracted/exploded and Beanstalk does this for you internally. But when you use the pipeline, you need to upload the exploded files directly instead of the WAR. It seems that the AWS Codepipeline is still not WAR friendly.

First off, to generate an exploded WAR file, you need to add the following to your build.gradle:

```
task explodedWar(type: Sync) {
into "${buildDir}/exploded"
with war }
```

To generate the exploded folder, you need to run the following task through your terminal using the command:

```
./gradlew explodedWar
```

You will find a folder named `exploded` in the `build` folder where you will be able to see the contents of the exploded WAR.

Here is the following builspec.yml file you can use to build the code and deploy it using the pipeline. The environment used by me is `Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2`:

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - echo Installing gradle
      - wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
      - unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entering pre build
  build:
    commands:
      - /opt/gradle/gradle-7.1.1/bin/gradle clean
      - /opt/gradle/gradle-7.1.1/bin/gradle explodedWar
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entering post build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: build/exploded/
  discard-paths: no
```

You can check the [AWS buildspec.yml documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) for more syntax and features depending on your use case.